# Find last column with data, clear two columns from right

Tags: excel, vba

I have VBA for copy paste function. I would like to have the same for clear cells function. I want to find last cell in rows 10:31 with data from the right and clear two last columns in rows 10:31.

I use `lastcolumn = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToRight).Column` to find last cell with data from the right.

How I can set rows 10:31 and implement ClearContents to do the work?

```
10 data data1 data2 data3 data4 data5 data6 data7 data8
11 data data1 data2 data3 data4 data5 data6 data7 data8
12 data data1 data2 data3 data4 data5 data6 data7 data8
13 data data1 data2 data3 data4 data5 data6 data7 data8
14 data data1 data2 data3 data4 data5 data6 data7 data8
...
31 data data1 data2 data3 data4 data5 data6 data7 data8
```

The idea is that if I click button once "data8 and data7" will be cleared, then I click button once again "data6 and data5" will be cleared. Again button clicked "data4 and data3" are gone and so on...
Here is my code:

```
Sub Remove()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim lastcolumn As Integer
Dim lastrow As Long

'finds the last used column coming from the right
lastcolumn = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToRight).Column
Worksheets("Price calculation").Range("10:31").Offset(0, 1).ClearContents

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to use `xlToLeft`, not `Right`. @Cyril has corrected for this in his solution :)

Comment: you also need to qualify references in your last column calculation.  hence the With statement in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want a specific range of cells contents cleared, name the exact range such as:

```
With Worksheets("Price calculation")
    lc = .cells(10,.columns.count).end(xltoleft).column
    .Range(.cells(10,lc-2),.cells(31,lc)).ClearContents
End with
```

Comment: I am getting an error for `.Range(.cells(10,lc-2),.cells(31,lc)).ClearContents`. I have edited my question. Maybe I was not so clear about what is my point.

Comment: @user7202022 this should work for you.  What is the error you're receiving?  If row 1 has NO DATA then lc = 1 and lc-2 = -1, which cannot be a column.  Note that lc is using ROW 1 to determine, in my example; you need to adjust that.  I will update to display using ROW 10.

Comment: @user7202022 additional point, if you have data out to different column counts, and that is of consequence, you would need to do something different than this post shows (probably iterating through the rows and for each row clearing contents).